# Using a normal distribution in GPU machine and CUDA

Tags: cuda

I have a question of using GPU machine here. Now I'm working on a `CUDA` file. I want to put a random noise to my function, and I'm using a normal distribution of mean 0 and variance 1. But after several tries, I still can't make it work.

This is what I tried and I don't know why it didn't work. I'm using the my school's cluster to run the experiment.

```
I_TCS = ITCSAmp*curand_normal();
```

`I_TCS` and `ITCSAmp` here are my functions. I already both `curand.h` and `curand_kernel.h`. And the error messages I got were:

```
error: no instance of overloaded function "curand_normal" matches the argument list
```

Please let me know if you know some possible solutions. I'll really appreciate that!

Comment: If you look at the [documentation](http://hpc.oit.uci.edu/nvidia-doc/sdk-cuda-doc/CUDALibraries/doc/CURAND_Library.pdf) you should see that `curand_normal` requires a single argument of type `curandState_t *`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've seen that. But on first line of the page 19, I thought I don't need to put that argument there. And I'll look through it in more details. Thank you!

Comment: I read the document more carefully this time. So does it mean that the following argument should work?
__device__ void curand_init(unsigned long long seed, unsigned long long sequence, unsigned long long offset, curandState_t *state)__device__ float curand_normal(curandState_t *state) 

Or should I add more things here? Many thanks!

Comment: The accepted answer below should give you all the info you need. Note that you only need to call `curand_init` once - then call `curand_normal` as many times as you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to use it:

```
__global__ void kernel(unsigned int * sobolDirectionVectors, curandStateSobol32 *state)
{

        curand_init(sobolDirectionVectors, 1234, &state[0]);

        float NormalRandomVariable = curand_normal(&state[0]);
}
```